# Does Neo4jTemplate save nodes recursively?

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

1.Does Neo4jTemplate save the nodes recursively like the aspectj mapping does?
Do we need to save on creation and then again called save after the relationships are added to the node. Also do we need to call save on each and everynode in the graph on creation or any time in the transaction.
**UPDATED**
2.Also when we save using the repository, does that save recursively?
3.What is advisable to persist the nodes,Neo4jTemplate or Repository or persist method ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does it partially if entities are annotated with @Fetch as far as I remember.

And only for outgoing references.

I personally rather do the manual persisting and then putting things together.

The repository persist() method only delegates to the template internally.